# Image Processing Libraries for Android

Tags: java, android, matlab, image-processing

I am currently developing an image processing application for android mobile phones and I would like to know what libraries would you guys recommend me based on your experience.
I have heard of [JJIL](http://code.google.com/p/jjil/) but I do not know how good it might be for what i want to achieve.
I need something that implements the basic image processing functions from Matlab toolbox, and i would also like to know if there are any alternatives to JJIL.
Additionally, i have heard it is possible to use Matlab's compiler to generate C code that would be useable in a standalone application, but has anybody ever did this before, for Java, adapting it to work in android environment?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least from the google code description, JJIL seems like exactly what you want. Are there specific things you want to do that JJIL doesn't support?

It is possible to compile Matlab code. Look up mex in the matlab documentation. I have used Java code within Matlab, but never the opposite.

Comment: Basicly, from what I could see and from what the classes structure suggest, JJIL focuses a big load on being able to deal with differents types of storage of image files in different types of mobile devices, making it compatible between them and also allowing for compatibility between J2ME and J2SE image storage.  In my case, I just wanted a library focused on the processing algorithms for images stored/loaded as the Android class format (Bitmap). Functions like resize, applying filters of sorts, transforms, and so on.